# JQUERY Disable and insert HTML into button on submit

Tags: jquery, forms

I would like to change text and disable the button of a form on submit. The code below does not work..

```
// DISABLE SUBMIT BUTTON ON CLICK
$('#contactform').submit(function() {
  $(this).find("button[type='submit']").text("<i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i>");
  $(this).find("button[type='submit']").prop('disabled',true);
});
```

**EDIT**

The HTML is:

```
<button type="submit" id ="myButtonLead" name="myButtonLead" class="btn form-cta">
  RICHIEDI INFORMAZIONI</br>
  <p class="sub">&Egrave; GRATIS!</p>
</button>
```

Expected behaviour is to change the button's HTML content (replace the current text with the font awesome icon). 
Any hint? :)

Comment: What is your expected behaviour? Set text content or change HTML button's content??? Provide expected HTML markup

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8c08a5jc/1/

Comment: So use `html()`, not `text()` and use relevant quotes inside string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.text("<i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i>");
```

should be

```
.html("<i class='fa fa-cog fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw'></i>");
```

Please check below snippet for more understanding.

```js
// DISABLE SUBMIT BUTTON ON CLICK
$('#contactform').submit(function() {
  $(this).find("button[type='submit']").html("<i class='fa fa-cog fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw'></i>");
  $(this).find("button[type='submit']").prop('disabled',true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="contactform">
  <button type="submit" id ="myButtonLead" name="myButtonLead" class="btn form-cta">
    RICHIEDI INFORMAZIONI</br>
  <p class="sub">&Egrave; GRATIS!</p>
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: You need to use `.html()` not `text()`  EDIT: well, not sure indeed what is OP expected behaviour

Comment: you can use `.text()` on `<button>`, on `<input>` you need `.val()`.

Comment: that will replace the text with the escaped HTML

Comment: @Tyr `text()` uses internally `createTextNode` method, not what OP is expecting

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
// DISABLE SUBMIT BUTTON ON CLICK
$('#contactform').submit(function() {
  $(this).find('button[type="submit"]').html('<i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i>');
  $(this).find('button[type="submit"]').prop('disabled',true);
});
```

My advice is be consistent with the quotes use. I will recommend you to start always with single quotes and use double inside or escaping `\"` when needed.